Autoscroll with hellopangea / react-beautiful-dnd nested lists
I'm looking to recreate something like this (https://dnd.hellopangea.com/iframe.html?args=&globals=backgrounds.grid:!false&id=examples-board--scrollable-columns&viewMode=story) wherein there's a vertically-scrollable list of horizontally-scrollable lists, and the outer lists can be reordered and the tasks within the lists can be dragged both within their original list and to other lists. I'm able to achieve that, but I'm not able to have the outermost container scroll when a task is being dragged from one horizontal list to another.
Is this perhaps due to the fact that in the example, the list of lists exists at the window level, and so the package is able to handle the scrolling properly? My list of lists cannot occupy the whole window, so I'm not sure exactly what to do (and there's no source code!)
Note: the 'inner' lists must be horizontally-scrollable, as well as the 'outer' list of lists which must be vertically-scrollable. I can achieve the vertical autoscroll on task drag if I remove overflow-scroll from the inner lists, and I can get everything working properly without the vertical autoscroll on task drag if I add it back in, but I can't get both to work. Interestingly, the vertical autoscroll works when reordering the lists...
So the structure needs to be
<vertical scrollable>
 <horizontal scrollable>
 <horizontal scrollable>
</vertical scrollable>

